# Webscraping through Office Scripts without API, using getElementByID, etc

Tags: web-scraping, getelementbyid, office-scripts

Please assist:
I'm familiar with VBA and C++, but not with Java. Now wanting to delve into Office Scripts.

However, I want to know if I can achieve the same as in VBA:
I am logging into niche websites and fetching data in tables using VBA Internet Controls (getElementByID()), etc.

As far as I know, these niche websites do not have an API, as the sample scenario of webscraping on the Microsoft website does:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/scenarios/noaa-data-fetch

I would like to know if I can log onto these websites, and then fetch information using HTML (getElementByID()) or similar?

I am just unsure if I can use Office Scripts directly, or if I require to include some library or something.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Your best bet would be to use Power Automate Desktop and then create an Office Script to add the data into your Excel file. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_O9eEotCT0U                You would add a parameter in your Office Script and load the JSON data into your Office Script.

Comment: Great, thank you. I have asked our IT department for permission to install it. Should they decline, is there a method to do it directly using Office Scripts?

Comment: If your IT department would decline that, then I would assume that your IT department would also not allow that in Office Scripts

Comment: It's a large corporate. We have access to Office Scripts and Office 365 in general. So we're allowed to use Office Scripts/Power Automate at office.com but may not download our own software until it is approved. I have asked if we may install PowerAutomate Desktop and they said that it has not been approved as of yet.

Comment: I work for a Big 3 Auto company and we have Office Scripts but we don't have Power Automate yet. So I am saying if your IT department doesn't yet allow Power Automate, then I am assuming that you won't be able to call API's from Office Scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to do this through Office Scripts alone. The [`fetch` command and REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/develop/external-calls) are the only ways to get data in a script directly from webservices. If you'd like to request the addition of a specific library, please use the **Send feedback** button in the Office Scripts Code Editor.

The discussion in the comments about using Power Automate is a reasonable path to pursue. The linked video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_O9eEotCT0U) is a good place to start.